# MySQL standalone

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL 5.5.27 on my MAC using the binary installer. I am able to run the mysql server with /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start. But I am not able to run the mysqld with standalone option. I get the following error:

```
120821 17:28:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
bin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
120821 17:28:03 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120821 17:28:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120821 17:28:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120821 17:28:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120821 17:28:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120821 17:28:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120821 17:28:04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Could you please help me to run the mysqld --standalone ?

Answer (score 1):

As it is saying, run "./mysql_upgrade -u  -p" first to create the frm file. If you're not able to create it, try running the script as superuser. 
Then run "./mysqld -u ", in case as superuser too.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Valerio, Thanks for your help. I have tried: bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p. It goes thro' all the checks and finally end up with an error:Could not create the upgrade info file '/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MySQL Servers datadir, errno: 13. Could please help me to fix this?

Comment: did you also try to gain your superuser privileges running sudo ./mysql_upgrade -u root -p? Your error resides in restricted permissions, running the script as superuser will make you pass over those restrictions. Or alternatively you could set different permissions to that folder, so that you can make operation even without superuser privileges

Comment: Thanks again. Now I am able to run the sudo bin/mysqld -u root after the upgrade. But it stuck at:Version: '5.5.27'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) for a long time. Is this normal?

Comment: It means that the service has started. By default it will automatically close after something like 28800 seconds of inactivity.
Run ./mysqld --verbose --help for more informations. To manually stop mysqld I think you have to run ./mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown

Answer (score 0):

To run mysqld on Mac w/o the "startup item", execute the following in Terminal.app

```
sudo su -
nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe &
```